# Python: Dealing with NaN Values using Imputer on Dataframe index wise

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, nan, imputation

I have a data with some NaN values and i want to fill the NaN values using `imputer`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer 
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=1) 
cleaned_data = imp.fit_transform(original_data)
```

so far I known `imputer` works on entire column Like this:

```
            Point1        Point2
S.No
             2              NaN
1            NaN            4
             2              NaN
             NaN            4
2            2              NaN
             NaN            4
```

After applying imputer the data looks like:

```
            Point1        Point2
S.No
             2              2
1            1              4
             2              2
             1              4
2            2              2
             1              4
```

but I want imputer works index wise name as S.No

```
            Point1        Point2
S.No
             2              1.33
1            1.333          4
             2              1.33
             0.667          4
2            2              2.667
             0.667          4
```

It is possible to implement `imputer` like this or not OR there are any  alternative methods exist to do like this in `python` on `DataFrame`.

Comment: What is `S.No` here? Index? And also I can't seem to reproduce your results. Is your data frame pandas data frame?

Comment: i import my data like this data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",index_col = [0]); yes!! `S.No` is index and yes!! my dataframe is pandas data frame

Comment: When I run your imputed transform, the Point1 column is filled with 4 instead of 1. Maybe you want to set the `axis = 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imp = Imputer(missing_values=np.NaN,strategy='mean',axis=1)
for S.No in range (start,end):
    for col in list(Data.select_dtypes(include=['float']).columns):
        Data[col][S.No] = imp.fit_transform(Data[col][S.No])
```